# VSC2013 、cocos2d-x 3.4 で webView を使うとリンクエラーが発生する

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Visual Studio Community 2013 で webView を含む cocos2d-x 3.4 のコードをビルドすると、以下の様なリンクエラーが発生します。

> error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class 
>   cocos2d::experimental::ui::WebView * __cdecl  cocos2d::experimental::ui::WebView::create(void)" (__imp_?create@WebView@ui@experimental@cocos2d@@SAPAV1234@XZ) が関数 "public: virtual bool __thiscall HelloWorld::init(void)" (?init@HelloWorld@@UAE_NXZ) で参照されました。

このエラーに対処するには、どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: webViewはiOSとAndroidでのみ使用可能です。

Comment: なんと、そういうことだったんですかー
ご教授ありがとうございましたー

Answer (score 1):

WebView は iOS と Android でのみ使用可能です。

---

*この投稿は [@h2so5 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8521/vsc2013-cocos2d-x-3-4-%e3%81%a7-webview-%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%83%b3%e3%82%af%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b#comment7714_8521) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*